# REST API parameters not working with nginx

Tags: nginx, rest-api, parameter

I'm having an issue with the server I'm working off of ignoring any parameters I send to the REST API. My local environment works perfectly, but for some reason the other environments don't.  I work with a DevOps team, so I'm trying to gather as much information as I can to pass on to them to help them fix the problem.

Examples of endpoints I've tried hitting:

`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=2`

`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?post_status=publish&page=4&posts_per_page=1&filter[posts_per_page]=1`

`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=2`

`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&per_page=1&filter[s]=blah`

Regardless of the endpoint I'm trying to hit the Headers link that is always returned is

`Link →<https://myurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?q&page=2>; rel="next"`

I found this post about nginx configuration issues: http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/problems/#query-parameters-are-ignored and changed the `try_files` line but the problem persists.

If anyone else has encountered this issue and has any tips for fixing it I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm pretty sure its a mapping/configuration issue with nginx.  Those requests need to be passed on to Apache or whatever is servicing the php requests.  Where are the errors coming from - nginx, Apache, WP?

Comment: There aren't actually any errors, it's just not accepting any filters/parameters.  The server is nginx.  No matter what the parameters I pass are, the Headers Link that is _always_ returned is `https://myurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?q&page=2>; rel="next"`

Comment: Do you have any caching plugins enabled?  Its possible the caching is returning the last cached data (ignores parameters).  Most caching plugin allow you to configure urls not to cache.

Comment: I did, but i disabled it and the problem persists.

Comment: Is this only occurring with the REST API, or with other pages as well? (Try `/?s=some+query` for example.)

Comment: well, the `/?s=some+query` doesn't return any results, but I have google search enabled so search results are loaded at `/search/?q=some+query&submit=Search`

Comment: I am not sure why my answer was deleted but is it possible some of sites are upgraded to 4.7? I have similar issue and it was because of WordPress deprecate filter[]. However I was lucky enought to use this plugin to make it work again. https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter. Please delete me again :)

Comment: @powerfade917 I tried this but no results. Still getting the same error

Comment: @jenkma02 were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Snowball No I haven't been able to resolve it :(  Sounds like you're having similar issues?  Have you had any luck?

Comment: I was able to resolve it with the fix from this ticket in trac: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39432 But I only had the issue within the root of the http://example.org/wp-json/. Other endpoints (e.G. http://example.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/) did work. Have you checked your nginx server configuration file? This is my working location block:

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

Comment: Thanks @Snowball. The posts come through just fine, but filters aren't applied to the results at all. No matter what filter I include, the return link is always `<https://myurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?q&page=2>; rel="next"`

Comment: I will give the location block thing a try too. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If your virtual host looks like this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
```

change it to this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

Adding **$is_args** (which will print a ? character if query arguments are found) will allow WordPress to properly receive and interpret the query parameters

Comment: I'm a support representative and I just worked through a support ticket with a user where this answer resolved the issue for them. This would be useful to add to any WordPress/Nginx configuration docs like this one for example: https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/

Comment: I'm glad something I've wrote helps someone after 6 years